How to pass shell variable returned from pythonscript into another shell to run another pythonscript in Makefile rule?
I am trying for several hours and researched how to pass a shell variable which is returned from a pythonscript into another shellscript to run another pythonscript.
I have an example below:
MyRule:
export VAR=$(shell python.exe mySkript1.py someInputs); \
echo $$VAR; \
$(shell python.exe mySkript2.py someInputs2 $VAR}) \
echo $$VAR;

How can I pass the variable VAR into the second shell line?
I tried the following but none of them made it:
"$VAR"
$$VAR
$(VAR)

.

Why are you using $(shell) to run shell commands in a make recipe?  Commands in a make recipe are already run via a shell, and your second $(shell ...) in particular likely yields an invalid recipe.  But also, the $VAR in the second $(shell ...) is expanded by make not by the shell, so it does not see the environment variable added earlier in the recipe.  Change that to $$VAR, as in your echo commands.

When I use $$VAR, then I get  a warning: undefined variable 'VAL'

"When I use $$VAR, then I get a warning: undefined variable 'VAL'" -- your recipe suggests that you're running make with a POSIX shell such as Bash as the SHELL, but neither Bash nor make complain about references to undefined variables.  If the shell underneath is actually PowerShell then you need to write your recipes in PowerShell (or switch to Bash).

There is no Makefile variable $VAR so it gets replaced with the empty string.
Anyway, don't use $(shell ...) inside recipes.
MyRule:
    export VAR=$$(python.exe mySkript1.py someInputs); \
    echo $$VAR; \
    python.exe mySkript2.py someInputs2 "$$VAR"; \
    echo "$$VAR"


Hello, basically the code works when I dont use "$$VAR" as parameter. But, when  use "$$VAR" as parameter, I get an "command not found" error. How can I fix it?

I removed the quotes "". Now it works!.

That sounds like you have additional errors somewhere. Perhaps see When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?

You could use make variables and do:
VAR=$(shell python.exe mySkript1.py someInputs)

MyRule:
      python.exe mySkript2.py someInputs2 "$(VAR)"

With the version of GNU-Make that I happen to be using right now, VAR is not expanded unless needed so running other recipes will not necessarily cause an unneeded execution of python.exe, but I'm not sure what other versions of make will do.
Whether or not this is a good idea for your use case will vary.

That alternative is a bit risky.  If VAR ends up containing " characters, or $ characters, or certain other things, then they will end up being processed by the shell, not taken as literals.  The situation would be improved, but not altogether resolved, by quoting the expansion of $(VAR) with single quotes instead of double quotes.  The same is not true for capturing the first script's output in a shell variable, and letting the shell expand it (inside double quotes).
